# How to make the 'DrawText' rectangle just fit the text?

Tags: c, winapi

The documentation [[ here ]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173962(v=vs.85).aspx) says if we use the `DT_CALCRECT` flag, then below would be done :

> Determines the width and height of the rectangle. If there are
>   multiple lines of text, DrawText uses the width of the rectangle
>   pointed to by the pRect parameter and extends the base of the
>   rectangle to bound the last line of text. If there is only one line of
>   text, DrawText modifies the right side of the rectangle so that it
>   bounds the last character in the line. In either case, DrawText
>   returns the height of the formatted text but does not draw the text.

It is clear from the description that `DT_CALCRECT` will make the `DrawText` **not** to draw the content so that I should do something like

```
DrawTextExA(hdc, fromsqlite->descrip, -1, &rect, DT_CALCRECT, NULL);
// On debugging, I can see that rect is being modified in the above step.
if (DrawTextExA(hdc, fromsqlite->descrip, -1, &rect,
            DT_LEFT | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK, NULL) == 0) {
MessageBox(NULL, L"DrawText failed", NULL, MB_OK);
}
```

Now the problem is that the width of the rectangle should be fixed. So, I just want the base of the rectangle `rect` to be extended. In my case though `fromsqlite->descrip` which is retrieved from a `sqlite` database is always considered as `single-line` text.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DT_WORDBREAK` should be added to break the single line of text.

`DT_CALCRECT` should be combined with the final format to get the rectangle.

Documentation: [DrawText function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) (GDI function)

> `DT_WORDBREAK`
>   Breaks words. Lines are automatically broken between
>   words if a word would extend past the edge of the rectangle specified
>   by the lpRect parameter. A carriage return-line feed sequence also
>   breaks the line.
>
> If this is not specified, output is on one line.

Example:

```
RECT rc={ 0, 0, 200, 0 };
const wchar_t* text = L"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5";
UINT format = DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK;
DrawText(hdc, text, -1, &rc, format | DT_CALCRECT);
DrawText(hdc, text, -1, &rc, format);
```

Output would be similar to the following (depending on font size)

> word1 word2 word3
>  word4 word5

Is `DT_EDITCONTROL` necessary?

Consider this example:

```
text = L"SingleLinexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
format = DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_WORDBREAK;
DrawText(hdc, text, -1, &rc, format | DT_CALCRECT);
DrawText(hdc, text, -1, &rc, format);
```

This time "word" could be longer that rectangle's width, line will not break, text will spill over on the right side.

You may wish to combine the format with `DT_EDITCONTROL` or other flags like `DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS` to make sure there is no spill over on the right side.

`DrawTextEx` uses the same `DT_XXXX` flags.

Side note: if your text is UTF-8, you can convert to UTF-16 using `MultiByteToWideChar`, rather than using `DrawTextA` which expects ANSI input.

Comment: Cheers pal ! I am looking into this.. `DrawTextA` is intentional here as I am strictly dealing with ANSI input.

Comment: Well, this worked ! A nice technique indeed. But I didn't use the ` DT_EDITCONTROL` flag which I feel is not necessary here..

Comment: @sjsam You are using `DT_EDITCONTROL` in your sample. As this answer correctly shows, you have to use the same flags in the first call to `DrawText` as in the second call to `DrawText` otherwise the calculated rectangle will be incorrect.

Comment: Also text could spill over on the right side of the rectangle without `DT_EDITCONTROL`. See updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your time and valuable suggestions. The problem with `DT_CALCRECT` is that if the text is not big enough, then the width of the rectangle will be made smaller, ie the `rect.right` value will be decreased. If I am not mistaken, there is no easy workaround for this..

Comment: You can just make a copy of the rectangle, `rcText = rc` then change the height of `rc`

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought of, and doing at the moment.. :)